# unable to redirect to the line from where the action method is called in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have the following View code in which I am displaying a list of flights.

```
@using Airline_Reservation_System.Models;
@{ 
    AirlineContext ac = new AirlineContext();
    var ddlcabin = ac.Cabins.ToList();
}


    <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center py-5">
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                    <div class="flight mb-2">
                        <div class="info-label">
                            <span>Flight Info</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="toFrom">
                            <h3 id="FCity_@item.FlightID">@item.FromCity </h3>
                            <span><i class="fa mx-4 fa-plane"></i></span>
                            <h3 id="TCity_@item.FlightID">@item.ToCity</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info d-flex">
                            <p class="me-2 " id="DDate_@item.FlightID">@item.DepartureDate.ToShortDateString()</p>
                            <p class="me-2" id="DTime_@item.FlightID">@item.DepartureTime.ToShortTimeString()</p>
                            <p class="me-2 " id="ATime_@item.FlightID">@item.ArrivalTime.ToShortTimeString()</p>
                            <select id="CFare_@item.Fare" class="form-control me-2">

                                @foreach (var re in ddlcabin)
                                {
                                    <option value="@re.CabinsId">@re.CabinName (@re.Fare)</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                            <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" onclick="Save(@item.FlightID,@item.CabinsId)">select </button>
                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Select", "ReserveFlight", "Flights", new { @class = "btn SelectFlight btn-primary" })*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    }

               

            }

        }

<script>
    function Save(id, cabinsId) {
        var Fid = id;
        var cid = cabinsId;
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("signUp","User")';
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url:'/Flights/ReserveFlight',
            data: { FlightId: Fid, CabinId: cid }
        });
    }
        </script>
```

Here in the script section, I called the first action method signUp in the User controller and after that, in the Ajax call, I posted data on the URL `/Flights/ReserveFlight`

but the problem is that In the first call the control goes to the signUp method in the User controller, but before opening its view the control automatically goes to action called by ajax means to this action which is:

```
public ActionResult ReserveFlight(int FlightId, int CabinId)
        {
            FlightReservation reserve = new FlightReservation();
            reserve.CabinsId = CabinId;
            reserve.Id = FlightId;
            reserve.PessengerId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
            db.FlightReservations.Add(reserve);            
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();            
        }
```

this action gets executed and on the line:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

it shows an exception because the pessengerId is going null.
when I continue it then the view of the signUp method gets displayed.
here is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("signUp", "User", FormMethod.Post,))
    {

        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "fullName" } })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>

                <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Genderid, ViewBag.gender as SelectList, "--select gender--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "gender" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", id = "dob" } })
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.contact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", id = "contact" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cnic, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "cnic" } })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityId, ViewBag.cityList as SelectList, "--select city--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "city" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "email" } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "password" } })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "cpassword" } })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-10">
                    <input type="button" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="signUp()" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function signUp() {
                var obj = {
                    FullName: $('#fullName').val(),
                    Genderid: $('#gender').val(),
                    DOB: $('#dob').val(),
                    Cnic: $('#cnic').val(),
                    CityId: $('#city').val(),
                    contact: $('#contact').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    password: $('#password').val(),
                    cPassword: $('#cpassword').val()
                };
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/User/signUp",
                    data: obj,
                    success: function () {
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

when I submit the form, Data gets inserted into the database but In the ajax call section, the error callback function is executed and alert shows

> failed

Comment: Where is the call for signUp post method? Please post the full code

Comment: window.location.href = '@Url.Action("signUp","User")';

Comment: window.location.href = '@Url.Action("signUp","User")';  will call the get method without parameter. Where is the Post method being called. Please post the View code.

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanthPappannan Now the question is edited.

Comment: The Form post is initiated from the view via Submit button. There is no javascript/ jQuery involved here and so it wont return to script code because the method was not called by the script. If you need to bring the control back to script, write a submit event in jQuery and then call the post method via Ajax and then in Ajax success method you can get back the control to script.

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanthPappannan I tried your suggestion and after that, I am facing new problems which I added into the question. Now you can check the post again and please suggest the solution If you got my point.

Comment: Now again there is some code missing and I cannot understand few parts of it. Always post the whole controller, model and view code if you are asking a MVC question. 
Now from your question I see there are 2 problems. 1. Signup is called and Reserve Flight is called even before Signup renders view - My question is Why there are 2 methods returning views being called in the same flow. This is wrong. 
2.  Your Ajax call could fail for so many reasons - Proper way to do ajax submit- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-form-submit-using-serialize-form-data-into-a-model/

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanthPappannan can I have you email or contact so that I can send you the whole code which you will check and suggest modifications.